# How do I get v0 using superposition in this circuit?

Tags: circuit-analysis, voltage-divider, superposition

I'm trying to get the value of \$V_o\$ in this circuit. Here's the circuit:

[image]

Using **Superposition** theorem:

So first, we remove the voltage source and replace it with a short circuit. Then we calculate \$V_o\$.

Second, we remove the 1A current source replace it with an open circuit, then we calculate \$V_o\$.

Third, we remove 2A current source and replace it with an open circuit, then we calculate \$V_o\$.

Finally, we should add the three values of \$V_o\$ that we got in each case and thus we get the final answer of the total \$V_o\$.

My problem is that I'm unable to calculate the value of \$V_o\$ in each case, what exactly should I do after removing the source to get \$V_o\$. Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you pick a single source to use in your 1st analysis and, for **ALL** the other sources, you make them short (voltages) or open (current). That's how superposition works for each source. Then you add the individual voltages derived for each \$V_O\$ to produce the final value of \$V_O\$.

In other words:

Use one source with the others disabled then step and repeat for each source: -

[image]

Comment: Oh okay! got it. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The **superposition** principle states that the voltage across (or current
through) an element in a linear circuit is the algebraic sum of the voltages across (or currents through) that element due to each independent source *acting alone*.

So you have to turn off all the sources (shorting voltage sources and opening current sources) except the source you would like to know its response on \$V_o\$.

In your problem you have 3 sources, so you will have 3 values that their sum will produce \$V_o\$.

Here is our original circuit.

[image]

**First step:**

Remove l1 and l2 current sources and calculate the voltage across R4.
Assume it is \$v_1\$.

[image]

**Second step:**

Remove B1 and l1 sources, and calculate the voltage across R4 again. 
Assume it is \$v_2\$.

[image]

**Third step:**

Remove B1 and l2 sources, and calculate the voltage across R4 again.
Assume it is \$v_3\$.

[image]

**Final step:**

Calculate the algebraic sum.

\$V_o\$= \$v_1 + v_2 + v_3 \$.